# Dynamo DB Query Filter Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Running a Node.js serverless backend through AWS.

**Main objective:** to filter and list all LOCAL jobs (table items) that included the available services and zip codes provided to the filter.

Im passing in multiple zip codes, and multiple available services.

`data.radius` would be an array of zip codes = to something like this:`[ '93901', '93902', '93905', '93906', '93907', '93912', '93933', '93942', '93944', '93950', '95377', '95378', '95385', '95387', '95391' ]`

`data.availableServices` would also be an array = to something like this `['Snow removal', 'Ice Removal', 'Salting', 'Same Day Response']`

I am trying to make an API call that returns only items that have a matching `zipCode` from the array of zip codes provided by `data.radius`, and the `packageSelected` has a match of the array `data.availableServices` provided.

***API CALL***

```
import * as dynamoDbLib from "./libs/dynamodb-lib";
import { success, failure } from "./libs/response-lib";

export async function main(event, context) {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const params = {
    TableName: "jobs",
    FilterExpression: "zipCode = :radius, packageSelected = :availableServices",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":radius": data.radius,
      ":availableServices": data.availableServices
    }
  };

  try {
    const result = await dynamoDbLib.call("query", params);
    // Return the matching list of items in response body
    return success(result.Items);
  } catch (e) {
    return failure({ status: false });
  }
```

Do I need to map the array of zip codes and available services first for this to work?

Should I be using comparison operators? 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.QueryFilter.html

Is a sort key value or partition key required to query and filter? (the table has a sort key and partition key but i would like to avoid using them in this call)

Im not 100% sure on how to go about this so if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be wonderful and greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Still trying to figure this out! lol its been a dog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what your `dynamodb-lib` refers to but here's an example of how you can scan for attribute1 in a given set of values and attribute2 in a different set of values. This uses the standard AWS JavaScript SDK, and specifically the high-level document client.

Note that you cannot use an equality (`==`) test here, you have to use an inclusion (`IN`) test. And you cannot use `query`, but must use `scan`.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

let dc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({'region': 'us-east-1'});

const data = {
  radius: [ '93901', '93902', '93905', '93906', '93907', '93912', '93933', '93942', '93944', '93950', '95377', '95378', '95385', '95387', '95391' ],
  availableServices: ['Snow removal', 'Ice Removal', 'Salting', 'Same Day Response'],
};

// These hold ExpressionAttributeValues
const zipcodes = {};
const services = {};

data.radius.forEach((zipcode, i) => {
  zipcodes[`:zipcode${i}`] = zipcode;
})

data.availableServices.forEach((service, i) => {
  services[`:services${i}`] = service;
})

// These hold FilterExpression attribute aliases
const zipcodex = Object.keys(zipcodes).toString();
const servicex = Object.keys(services).toString();

const params = {
  TableName: "jobs",
  FilterExpression: `zipCode IN (${zipcodex}) AND packageSelected IN (${servicex})`,
  ExpressionAttributeValues : {...zipcodes, ...services},
};

dc.scan(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error', err);
  } else {
    for (const item of data.Items) {
      console.log('item:', item);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: with a little tweaking for my application, it works! Thank you very much!