# DynamoDB adding a global seconday index to existing table

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a DynamoDB table storing scheduled job information. In my base table, I have a `partionKey` of `userId`, and a `sortKey` of `jobId`.

**List of attributes:**

`[streetAddress, streetAddress2, city, propertyState, zipCode, propertySqft, packageSelected, createdAt, startDate, totalPrice, invoiceNumber, status]`

I want to create a global secondary index, so I can have it as a "job queue" so I can make an API request to query and filter through the`zipCode(number)`attribute and `packageSelected(string)` attribute to return location based and service based information. Ill be passing in multiple zip codes and specific service information to filter the attributes.

How do I create the index to replicate the base table information?

Comment: link to my recent question in relation to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719484/dynamo-db-query-filter-node-js

Comment: You can do it through the DynamoDB console. or maybe you would like to do by code?

Comment: yes I need to do it by code Node.js through an api call.

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

> **UpdateTable**
>
> Modifies the provisioned throughput settings, **global secondary indexes**, or DynamoDB 
>    Streams settings for a given table.[info](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateTable.html)

```
 {
    TableName: 'job',
   AttributeDefinitions: [ 
      { 
     "AttributeName": "zipCode",
     "AttributeType": "N"
      },
     { 
     "AttributeName": "packageSelected",
     "AttributeType": "S"
      }
      ],
    GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdates: [{ 
            Create: { 
    IndexName: 'index_zip', 
    KeySchema: [
        { // Required HASH type attribute
            AttributeName: 'zipCode',
            KeyType: 'HASH',
        },
        { // Optional RANGE key type for HASH + RANGE secondary indexes
            AttributeName: 'packageSelected', 
            KeyType: 'RANGE', 
        }
    ],
    Projection: { // attributes to project into the index
        ProjectionType: 'ALL', // (ALL | KEYS_ONLY | INCLUDE)

    },
    ProvisionedThroughput: { // throughput to provision to the index
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1,
    },
    },
    },

    ],
  }
```